# Cannot find class org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, websphere

we have upgraded our Project Spring Version from **3.1.2.RELEASE** to **4.3.25.RELEASE**.

I didn't found any Code related Errors. But Junit Test cases are failing by throwing below Error

> Cannot find class
>   [org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

**Error Log**

```
Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 10, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.979 sec <<< FAILURE!
testMergeInProgressStatus(com.perceptive.portal.idm.domain.AccountTest)  Time elapsed: 0.021 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    ....
    ....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'userAdminViewController': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userProfileService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: 
**Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer]** 
for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0' defined in class path resource [UserAdminTest-portlet.xml]; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
```

**UserAdminTest-portlet.xml content is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />

    <bean id="velocityEngineFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
     <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/classes/mailTemplates/"/>
   </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="webBindingInitializer">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
                <property name="validator" ref="hibernateValidator" />
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="hibernateValidator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="validationMessageSource">
            <ref bean="messageSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>content.messages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

The same code is worked without fail with below dependencies

```
<spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

We have changed above dependencies with below ones as the part of upgrade

```
<spring.version>4.3.25.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

with above dependencies it throws this exception at the time of executing test cases
**Cannot find class
org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**

Anyway i have changed spring-xx-xsd schema's to 4.0 but no luck

Comment: The class `ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` has been removed, use the regular `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [M.deinum](http:///users/2696260/m-deinum)

I have followed Your suggestion & I resolved this issue by doing few more things

Placed this code inside **UserAdminTest-portlet.xml**

```
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
        <property name="order" value="1" />

    </bean>
```

After that it throwed this

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/spi/resourceloading/ResourceBundleLocator
```

For this in pom.xml, I have upgraded hibernate validator version to

```
<hibernate.validator.version>6.1.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
```

Then i got another issue,

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: 
Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, 
or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
```

I have placed javax-el dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
</dependency>
```

**Then, Build Success.**

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="some-name" value="provide value here" />
    <property name="some-name" value="provide value here" />
</bean>
```

The class `org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is not found because it was deprecated and even it Spring Framework from 5.x.

Make sure you have to update Spring Framework version as 5.3.14 or onward.

In newer versions of Spring, you have to use:

```
org.springframework.web.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
```

instead of

```
org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
```

e.g.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="some-name" value="provide value here" />
    <property name="some-name" value="provide value here" />
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>5.3.14</version> 
</dependency>
```

Make sure you add the above dependency in your `pom.xml` and replace

```java
org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
```

with

```java
org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).